# Is there a word for 'acting impulsively'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am looking for a single-word verb that means "*acting impulsively*". For example,

> "You can never tell what Harley is going to do. She always *[acts impulsively]* without thinking things through."

I'd like it to be as generic as possible. "*splurge*" captures the idea I'm looking for, but the connotations of money don't work for me.

Comment: I think the proverb "look before you leap" and related phrases like "leap without looking" are familiar enough that you could probably just use *leaps* here and your meaning would be clear, even if you change *looking* to *thinking things through*.

Comment: whats wrong with "acts"?

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of synonyms of ***impetuous*** viz - : *impulsive, rash, hasty, overhasty, reckless, heedless, foolhardy, incautious, imprudent, injudicious, ill-conceived, ill-considered, unplanned, unreasoned, unthought-out, unthinking; spontaneous, impromptu, spur-of-the-moment, precipitate, precipitous, headlong, hurried, rushed*.

None of them are verbs, but perhaps you can derive a verb from one of them - such as ***she always rushes in without thinking***.

Answer (score 2):

> "You can never tell what Harley is going to do. She always ***[jumps in](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jump)*** without thinking things through."

[jump (in)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jump)

> 2.5 (of a person) make a sudden, impulsive rush to do something:
>   *‘Gordon jumped to my defence’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jump

Answer (score 0):

Like to add another with a lighter note, 'reacts', as oppose to 'responds'.   The use of 'reacts' in the example sentence would have conveyed the intensity of impulsiveness.   It is a toned-down version of the other words given in the answers above and, supposed, would be an alternative choice of words for asker and others.

[To respond or react](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/focus-forgiveness/201609/react-vs-respond)

But if anyone feels for other stronger words, these should serve vividfully well, 'barks', 'launches', 'explodes' or 'blasts'.

Comment: Hi and welcome to ELU Stack Exchange. Please check out the Help Center's page on {how to answer a question](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) here. Right now, this is more like a comment than an answer, and the help page can give suggestions about how to make it a more useful answer.

Comment: Why do you think it is more like a comment?  My answer looks like an answer.  It is generic and it does conver the meaning in the intented sentence.

Comment: you don't explain why you think there is a difference between "react" and "respond," and "react" on its own doesn't convey impulsivity, which is a key part of the question.  A comment on how "react" differs from "respond" could spur a clarification to the question, but still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

She always *leaps* without thinking things through.

This proposal comes from the idiom "look before you leap."

> Think carefully about what you are about to do before you do it.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Look+before+you+leap

Answer (score 0):

Though not a single-word verb, the following may work.

> "You can never tell what Harley is going to do. She always *has **knee-jerk** reactions*."

ODO:

> **[knee-jerk](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/knee-jerk)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** [attributive] (of a response) automatic and **unthinking**.
>   ‘a knee-jerk reaction’
>
> ‘Everything he says about these issues is knee-jerk and over-bearing
>   and made up of half-pieces of information he doesn't fully
>   understand.’
>
> ‘There will be no knee-jerk reactions and I firmly believe we'll get
>   ourselves out of this.’

Answer (score 0):

She always *charges ahead* without thinking things through.

I haven't found a definition.  But here's my picture of it: you are on a walk in the woods.  Harley is the one out front.