# What do you call the behaviour where someone is a bit too hasty and takes an action without any preparation

Tags: single-word-requests

For a very specific example, say you have a software developer who makes some changes to a product, then does no testing of the changes and then releases the product only to find that the customer finds the product no longer works.  The person is too hasty and not diligent enough to follow a careful process.

Comment: I think the answer is in your question: "hasty". Collins Cobuild : If you describe a person or their behaviour as hasty, you mean that they are acting too quickly, without thinking carefully,

Comment: Impulsive is a word that comes to mind. Not consulting other members of the team. Do these other members help or hinder?

Comment: Generally, the person is **careless**.

Comment: This question was precipitately closed. The answer to which closure refers is incomplete in respect of the relevant vocabulary. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: Welcome! Please read the following: "***single-word-requests** This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."* One reason for the existence of this rule is so we can know whether you want a noun, a verb, or an adjective. (This probably explains why your question was closed) Thanks.

Comment: "Went off half cocked" sorta fits.

Comment: For your specific example, that person could be engaged in "cowboy coding"  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_coding and http://wiki.c2.com/?CowboyCoding ); more generally (but in the same theme) you could say that they "shoot from the hip", which means firing a pistol as quickly as possible after drawing it out of the holster, without taking time to prepare or aim, and which generally results in very poor marksmanship.

Comment: [Is there a word for acting impulsively {'Harley always {acts impulsively} without thinking things through.'}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359315/is-there-a-word-for-acting-impulsively/359335#359335) contains all the answers, but the question is formulated differently. And of course this question lacks research; looking for synonyms of 'hasty' soon gives the answers. Some are too ready to give multi-repeats of material already covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three words come to mind. All have connotations of haste and unfortunate consequences.

> Precipitate = If an action is precipitate, it is done sooner or faster than expected and without enough thought or preparation
> “Don't be precipitate - think it through before you make a decision.”
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precipitate?q=Precipitate)

> Impetuous =  likely to do something suddenly, without considering the results of your actions
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precipitate?q=Impetuous)

> Rash = careless or unwise, without thought for what might happen or result
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precipitate?q=Rash)

You may also like to research *foolhardy* and (for a bit of pretension) *temerarious*, although I think them slightly less suitable for your specification.

Answer (score 2):

The person's work is **slipshod**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/slipshod) has

> **slipshod**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> Characterized by a lack of care, thought, or organization.
>
> *Having witnessed the slipshod management here, it is not surprising the programmes they run result in little success.*

This covers the OP's specific case where the person isn't *only* hasty:

> The person is too hasty and not diligent enough to follow a careful process.

Comment: I like slipshod. Very appropriate. should have thought if that one myself! Slovenly work.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with *impetuous* and *impulsive*. You need something that discloses the irresponsibility and unprofessionalism of that software developer, so you would rather choose a more 'caustic' adjective.

I would also suggest

> ***incautious*** and ***imprudent***, why not ***superficial*** or ***spur-of-the-moment***.
> I also like
> ***overhasty*** and ***overconfident***

I guess it depends on which connotation you want to emphasise.