# A phrase meaning trail blazing without being concerned about the consequences to others

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm trying to remember or think a new of s phrase to describe somebody who both forges a path a head of them, trail blazing in a way, but does so at the consequences of others.

This **isn't** just the classic line from Jurrasic park:

> Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether they could, they didn't stop to think if they should.

Which is *both* trail blazing and *separately* oblivious to the *eventual* consequences, rather than the trail blazing process itself being the cause of consequences. Like if the *main* issue at Jurrasic was making indigenous species extinct and not even *bothering* to check if that would happen before hand.

But I'm trying to articulate a meaning that better fits this sort of sentence:

> They're (were a/an) ______, a bright star burning anybody in their path to success

Is there a phrase closer to that? I've considered:

> They [cut a wide swath(e)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cut-a-wide-swath), a bright star burning anybody in their path to success

But that doesn't fit exactly, nor does just trail blazing. The "burning anybody in their path" doesn't need to be drastic, but it's the careless/callousness I'm trying to get across. The person the phrase is for may even be aware of what they're doing has negative consequences, just without caring *what* those consequences are. Bulldozing was mentioned in comments, but that only fits for a slow deliberate action.

Am I thinking of a phrase that exists? If so what is it?

Comment: If the consequences are drastic, *bulldozing* a path toward progress might be more appropriate than forging one. You could qualify an existing expression, e.g., *The researchers brashly forged ahead, breaking new ground, but with little diplomacy.*

Comment: @DjinTonic bulldozing is closer, but that qualified expression is not a phrase in itself

Comment: At least near-duplicates: [What do you call the behaviour where someone is a bit too hasty and takes an act ...?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553710/what-do-you-call-the-behaviour-where-someone-is-a-bit-too-hasty-and-takes-an-act/553712#553712) // [What do you call a person that goes to extreme ends to accomplish a goal?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259795/what-do-you-call-a-person-that-goes-to-extreme-ends-to-accomplish-a-goal/259800#259800).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth they may be exact duplicates, I will check them out

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/553710/15661) is closest but I'd after a word, not a phrase.

Comment: Mixed and/or "top-heavy" metaphoric usage, maybe, but [*Ivan **blazed a roughshod trail** across the former death strip*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22blazed+a+roughshod+trail%22) might carry the intended "sod the consequences" allusion.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry, but apparently I can't chat. The Spanish suspended me (unjustly, imo), my chatting ability was suspended then across all sites. I contacted the powers that be who corrected this (only disallowing chat in the Spanish forum), and now I see I can't chat with you in the ELU chat. So back to square one. :) Sorry to post this here but I didn't know where else to post it. Getting slightly miffed by all this.

Comment: What is wrong with: *They were trailblazers who burned anybody in their path to success*? You've already got fire to work with; just play up its destructive aspect.

Answer (score 2):

A very obvious metaphor:

**Their scheme was being railroaded through.**

> *railroad* [verb] [transitive]
>
> ...
>
> 1b: to push through hastily or without due consideration

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/railroad)]

The active trampling of those in the way

> *railroad* [verb]:
>
> compel by coercion, threats, or crude means; synonyms: *dragoon*, *sandbag*

is mentioned by [Dictionary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/railroad).

and the expression 'railroad/ed through'

> - *Unfortunately, this scheme is being railroaded through Westminster under the pretext of immigration control.*

by [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/railroad)

To fit with OP's example, we can use the verbo-nominal multi word verb (and avoid a mixed metaphor):

They're railroading their way through, blasting aside anybody in their path to success.

Comment: *They're (were a/an) railroader* doesn't work though, unless they're working on a train.

Comment: cf 'He was telescoping Saturn.'

Comment: As *nouns*, I'd say ***railroad*** is a much more typically American usage than it is British, and looking at the AmE Google Books corpus it's maybe 100 times more common than the noun ***ramrod***, whereas in the BrE corpus, ***a railroad*** is only about 4-5 times more common than ***a ramrod***. In Britain we seem to be just as happy to use the verb form ***to railroad*** as Americans, but it seems that only Americans ever talk about ***ramrodding*** some new law through the legislature, even though in other contexts they don't seem to use that term so much.

Answer (score 1):

They **bulldozed** a path/their way through the objections

MW:

> Definition of bulldoze one's way
>
> **to move forward while forcing other people to move out of the way**
>
> *They rudely bulldozed their way through the crowd.*
>
> —often used figuratively
>
> *He bulldozed his way to the top without regard for people along the way.*

> **bulldoze** verb

> transitive verb
>
> 1: to coerce or restrain by threats : BULLY
>
> 2: to move, clear, gouge out, or level off by pushing with or as if with a bulldozer.
>
> 3: to force insensitively or ruthlessly
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1: to operate a bulldozer
>
> 2: to force one's way like a bulldozer

Comment: The OP rejected *bulldozing a path* when I proposed it in my comment.

Comment: I didn't see that - we might have crossposted. However, I think we can both agree that *Bulldozing [...] only fits for a slow deliberate action* is not so.